# Identify Helmet (possibly WW2 British)

Tags: world-war-two, clothing

[image]
[image][image]

Please help me identify it. I assume it's 1941.

Answer (score 5):

The insignia is the [Combined Operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combined_Operations_Headquarters) badge, worn by various units across all service branches (Royal Navy, British Army, RAF), but primarily by the [Commandos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Commandos). Unfortunately, the "BMB" stamp indicates the manufacturer, rather than a unit, with "BMB" indicating "[Briggs Motor Bodies Ltd of Dagenham](http://www.treasurebunker.com/forums/index.php?/topic/1514-british-ww1ww2-brodie-helmet-maker-stamps/)". The number appears to be a "Heat Number" and represents a batch of steel, and was used to allow a sample of helmets from each batch to be destructively tested for resistance against shrapnel, as the material properties would vary to some extent from "heat" to heat.

Comment: Do you think it's genuine? Very exciting stuff. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @user7332554 I'm afraid I have absolutely no idea... I'm not an expert - just someone with an interest and access to wiki/google. Things to look out for: it's in very good condition, perhaps suspiciously so; The insignia is slightly off-centre and features of the eagle and submachine gun are missing; the chin-strap rivets are brass, whereas others I've seen are steel (but I don't know enough to say brass was never used); I can't identify the "M A O tm" stamp, and google is no help. Also, check with a magnet - I believe it should be non-magnetic manganese steel. Maybe consult a trader?

Answer (score 1):

[The Insignia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:British_Commandos_Patch.svg) is of the Royal Marines 3 Commando Brigade, which makes it seem it is at least a representation of a British Brodie Helmet from the Commandos. You might want to take it to a expert to validate it is genuine.

Comment: Where would I find such an expert?

Comment: Assuming you live in England, I would try contacting your local museum. If they are not able to offer further information, they would be able to point you to someone who would be. Most Museum Curators would be glad to help.